# Low call volume using dedicated phone number with Twilio Programmable Voice Android

Tags: android, twilio, call, volume, twilio-programmable-voice

Tried experimenting with different audio focuses: AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT, AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN

Tried multiple Audio manager modes: MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, MODE_IN_CALL

Call volume is noticeably quieter than a normal phone call.

All volume levels are set to max.